# List mysql row values horizontally without pivoting

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pivot

In my table I have following columns

```
--loannumber--disbid--username--docs--
--------------------------------------
---1234567  -- 430  -- jhon   -- NCN --
-- same   ---- 425  -- sam    -- NPC --
-- same     -- 455  -- clin   -- Mis --
-- 4567891  -- 666  -- some1  -- NCN --
-- same     -- 777  -- some2  -- NPC --
```

and also I have a auto incremented primary key

What I want to do is filter it like this and show in datagridview

```
++ loannumber ++  NCN  ++  NPC  ++  MIS  ++
--   1234567  ++  430  ++  --   ++  --   ++
--    same    ++  --   ++  425  ++  --   ++
--    same    ++  --   ++  --   ++  455  ++
```

I tried with following sql

```
SELECT loannumber, 

      CASE WHEN docs='NCN'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'NCN',      
      CASE WHEN docs='NPC'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'NPC',
      CASE WHEN docs='Missing'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Missing'

FROM claimloans
```

but this only counts number of disbld's . I want to show them instead of count. Loannumber field is not compulsory. I'm planning to write a sproc and call it form winforms. someone please help me ?

```
  ++ NCN  ++  NPC   ++  MIS ++
  ++  430  ++  --   ++  --   ++
  ++  --   ++  425  ++  --   ++
  ++  --   ++  --   ++  455  ++
```

(this also okay !!)

This is working perfectly fine. but how can I eliminate null

```
SELECT loannumber, 

      CASE WHEN docs='NCN'THEN disblid END 'NCN',
      CASE WHEN docs='Missing'THEN disblid END 'Missing',
      CASE WHEN docs='NF'THEN disblid END 'NF'


FROM claimloans
```

Comment: the question is not too clear... why not just `CASE WHEN docs='NCN'THEN disbid END 'NCN', ...`?

Comment: Thanks sir your comments helps. but how can I eliminate null values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i understand you correctly, but try this:

```
SELECT loannumber, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN docs='NCN'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'NCN',
      SUM(CASE WHEN docs='Missing'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Missing',
      SUM(CASE WHEN docs='NF'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'NF'
FROM claimloans 
GROUP BY loannumber
```

Comment: No sir this counts the number of disbid, but I want to show them instead of count . :)

Comment: Use the same logic and replace **1** with **disblid** and **0** with **NULL** It should works as you wish to work ;)